# How do I install Dotnetnuke 5.04 using Web App Gallery Tool in ASP.NET Hosting control panel?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I want to install Dotnetnuke version 5.04 using the Web App Gallery Tool in the ASP.NET Hosting control panel. But in Web App Gallery, the Dotnetnuke version is 5.06, whereas I want to install version 5.04.

I tried to install it manually but have been unsuccessful. How can I install version 5.04 using the Web App Gallery?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Web Platform Installer you are going to only be able to install the most current version of DotNetNuke, you will need to complete a manual installation if you want a previous version.

If you are doing a new site setup though, i would strongly recommend using the most current version.